# Loading a Tensorflow checkpoint fails with tensorflow 2.2, compatibility info?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have been using the tensorflow Estimator API to train a model. I am saving and loading checkpoints this way:

```
estimator=tf.keras.estimator.model_to_estimator(keras_model=keras_model, model_dir=checkpoints_dir)

estimator.train  ...

estimator.predict ...
```

This works ok and I have been saving checkpoints files which look like:

```
model.ckpt.data-00000-of-000001
model.ckpt.index
model.ckpt.meta
```

However, I tried to load a checkpoint created with a version of tensorflow 1.15 with tensorflow 2.2 (on google colab), and now I get an error message.
Are checkpoint files compatible from tensorflow 1.15 forward? Should I export a "SavedModel" instead? I want to distribute a checkpoint file for a google colab notebook.

I really don't understand in the Tensorflow documentation how does the checkpoints compatibility work between versions. Any help?

The error message is:

> NotFoundError: Key estimator_global_step/.ATTRIBUTES/VARIABLE_VALUE not found in checkpoint
>        [[{{node save/RestoreV2}}]]
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> NotFoundError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
>   NotFoundError: Key estimator_global_step/.ATTRIBUTES/VARIABLE_VALUE not found in checkpoint
>        [[node save/RestoreV2 (defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/keras.py:332) ]]
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
>   RuntimeError: Key _CHECKPOINTABLE_OBJECT_GRAPH not found in checkpoint
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> NotFoundError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
>   NotFoundError: Key _CHECKPOINTABLE_OBJECT_GRAPH not found in checkpoint
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> NotFoundError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
>   /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py in restore(self, sess, save_path)
>      1313         # a helpful message (b/110263146)
>      1314         raise _wrap_restore_error_with_msg(
>   -> 1315             err, "a Variable name or other graph key that is missing")
>      1316 
>      1317       # This is an object-based checkpoint. We'll print a warning and then do
>
> NotFoundError: Restoring from checkpoint failed. This is most likely due to a Variable name or other graph key that is missing from the checkpoint. Please ensure that you have not altered the graph expected based on the checkpoint. Original error:
>
> Key estimator_global_step/.ATTRIBUTES/VARIABLE_VALUE not found in checkpoint
>        [[node save/RestoreV2 (defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/keras.py:332) ]]

If I change the tensorflow version like the following message, everything works fine.

> NOTE: Current TensorFlow version is 2.2.0-rc1. To use TF 1.x instead,
>   restart your runtime (Ctrl+M .) and run "%tensorflow_version 1.x"
>   before you run "import tensorflow".